# Interaction with a matching variable (time) in conditional logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interaction, matching, case-control-study

Short version: I want to look at the interaction between an explanatory variable and a matching variable in my conditional logistic regression. Is that possible?

I'm doing a case-control study on risk factors for a disease. The controls are matched to the cases by time: we've got historical register-based information on the population, so we've extracted information about the controls at the time when their matched case was diagnosed. I'm using conditional/matched logistic regression for the analysis.

One of the risk factors we're looking at is the region people live in. Specifically, there's one region that seems to be associated with the disease. We expected this, and we think it's because they do more diagnostic tests there.

Now we're wondering: was that region always at increased risk? Or did they only start testing more than the rest recently?
Or a different motivation for the same question: did the association with region and disease change over time, in a way that might introduce confounding for the other risk factors we're interested in?

What I'd like to do is split the data into three periods, and put the interaction of period/region into the model. But the model doesn't work. It can't calculate estimates for every combination, because period (or the underlying continuous time) is a matching variable.

Here are the ways I've tried to define the model. Twice by specifying an interaction term, first including the main effect and then excluding it. And then once by manually creating the interaction term and trying to model that. In every case, two of the terms can't be calculated.

[image]

And then finally I tried lumping together the time periods in one of the regions. That seemed to work, in as far as it has calculated all the estimates. But I have no idea whether it's valid or not. There is a tiny region in my real data that I'd be happy to do this with, if it's ok.

[image]

So my overall questions are: is there a way of looking into a time-varying effect of region? Is it my final lumping strategy, i.e. not calculating an estimate for every single combination? Or did we just lose the option to look at any of this when we chose to match by time?

PS I'm happy to share my data (what's a good way to do that?) if it would help.